# ACM SIG Proceedings: 6 authors total- 3 shared affiliation, also 2 shared affiliation

Tags: formatting, acm, author-number

On the website for the [ACM SIG Proceedings Template](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sigfaq#a17), there is an example where three authors all share the same affiliation (*See number 17*).

However, my situation is a bit different, I am part of a team of two other authors, we are all from the same Uni, also there is a team of two from a second University, and finally the third author who is from a different Uni entirely- but is by all accounts the most important author and should be first.

Ideally I would want it to look something like:

[image]

I tried the following code which results in a horrendous error:

```
\numberofauthors{6}
% Three authors sharing the same affiliation.
    \author{
      \alignauthor Ben King\\      
      \email{king@cs.berkeley.edu}
%
      \alignauthor Georgia Tobin\\     
      \email{tobin@cs.berkeley.edu}
%
      \alignauthor Gerald Murray\\    
      \email{murrray@cs.berkeley.edu}
%
      \sharedaffiliation
      \affaddr{Department of Electrical Engineering and Computer Science }  \\
      \affaddr{University of California, Berkeley }   \\
      \affaddr{Berkeley, CA 94720-1776 }\\

            \alignauthor Ben King\\      
      \email{king@cs.berkeley.edu}
%
      \alignauthor Georgia Tobin\\     
      \email{tobin@cs.berkeley.edu}
%
      \alignauthor Gerald Murray\\    
      \email{murrray@cs.berkeley.edu}
%
      \sharedaffiliation
      \affaddr{Department of Electrical Engineering and Computer Science }  \\
      \affaddr{University of California, Berkeley }   \\
      \affaddr{Berkeley, CA 94720-1776 }
          }
```

Does anyone know how I could render the authors to appear as I've made in that toy example, the photo?

**UPDATE***

The following is also awful:

```
\numberofauthors{5}
\author{
      \alignauthor Ben King\\      
      \email{king@cs.berkeley.edu}
      \alignauthor Georgia Tobin\\     
      \email{tobin@cs.berkeley.edu}
      \alignauthor Gerald Murray\\    
      \email{murrray@cs.berkeley.edu}
      \sharedaffiliation
      \affaddr{Department of Electrical Engineering and Computer Science}  \\
      \affaddr{University of California, Berkeley }   \\
      \affaddr{Berkeley, CA 94720-1776 }\\
      \\
      \alignauthor 
    Aba-Sah Dadzie\\                       % names
    \affaddr{KMi, The Open University, Milton Keynes, UK} \\            % affiliations
    \email{aba-sah.dadzie@open.ac.uk}  % emails
      \alignauthor 
    Gandalf Buscher, Frank Bensberg\\                       % names
    \affaddr{Osnabr{\"u}ck University of Applied Science, Germany} \\            % affiliations
    \email{\{g.buscher, f.bensberg\}@hs-osnabrueck.de}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
\numberofauthors{5} 
\author{
\alignauthor
Aba-Sah Dadzie\\
       \affaddr{KMi, The Open University}\\
       \affaddr{Milton Keynes, UK}\\
       \email{aba-sah.dadzie @open.ac.uk}
\alignauthor 
Gandalf Buscher, \mbox{Frank Bensberg} \\                       % names
\affaddr{Osnabr\"uck University of Applied Science, Germany} \\            % affiliations
\email{{g.buscher,f.bensberg} @hs-osnabrueck.de}
%
\and % go to new row
%
      \alignauthor Elisa M. Sibarani\\     
      \email{sibarani@iai.uni-bonn.de}
%
      \alignauthor S. Matthew English\\      
      \email{english@iai.uni-bonn.de}
%
      \alignauthor Simon Scerri\\    
      \email{scerri@iai.uni-bonn.de}
%
      \sharedaffiliation
      \affaddr{Rheinische Friedrich-Wilhelms-Universit\"at Bonn}  \\
      \affaddr{Fraunhofer-Institut f\"ur Intelligente Analyse und Informationssysteme IAIS}   \\
      \affaddr{Germany}
}
```

Comment: How to do this for 2017 master acm template?